# Java Spark how to save a JavaPairRDD<HashSet<String>, HashMap<String, Double>> to file?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, java-pair-rdd

I got this "`JavaPairRDD<HashSet<String>, HashMap<String, Double>>`" RDD after some complicated aggregations, want to save the result to file. I believe `saveAsHadoopFile` is a good API to do so, but am having trouble filling in the parameters for `saveAsHadoopFile(path, keyClass, valueClass, outputFormatClass, CompressionCodec)`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function and later on parse it to the desired result.

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile ("hdfs:///complete_path_to_hdfs_file/");
```

but if you want to use saveAsHadoopFile API then following method can be used.

```
saveAsHadoopFile(complete_path_to_file, HashSet.class, HashMap.class, TextOutputFormat.class)
```

you can also use `HadoopOutputFormat.class` as the last parameter

For more information, you can refer to this link
[HadoopFile](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-hadoops-input-format-and-output-forma)

Comment: How do we write it as an Avro File? I tried `pairRdd<String, Float>.saveAsHadoopFile("/user/cloudera/avro/", String.class, Float.class, AvroOutputFormat.class);` and got a `NullPointerException`